# Relation between $|(\nabla\times F)(u)|$ and $|\nabla F(u)|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, curl

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^\infty$. Let $u\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be nonnull. I am trying to understand if there is a relation between
$$|(\nabla\times F)(u)|\quad\text{ and }\quad |\nabla F(u)|,$$
(I mean if we can say if one is greater or less than the other)-

For simplicity, I was looking to the very special case in which $(\nabla\times F)(u) =\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial u_2},$ but I can not how to handle even this easier case.

Could someone please help with that?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you defining $\nabla F$, if $F$ is a vector function?

Comment: Presumably as a matrix, but then what is its modulus?

Comment: Yes, how do you define the norm of the $3\times 3$ matrix $DF(u)$? If, for example, I define $\|A\| = \max\{|a_{ij}|\}$, then I get $|(\nabla\times F)(u)|\le 2\sqrt3 \|DF(u)\|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more or less a consquence of abuse of notation.

We have
$$
|\nabla \times F|^2=|\partial_2f_3-\partial_3 f_2|^2+|\partial_3 f_1-\partial_1 f_3|^2+|\partial_1 f_2-\partial_2 f_1|^2
$$
and by absuse of notation, $\nabla$ also denotes the Jacobian $\nabla F$ whose norm is given by
$$
|\nabla F|^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^3 |\partial_i f_j|^2.
$$
Using the pointwise inequality $|x-y|^2 \leq 2 (|x|^2+|y|^2)$, we deduce that
$$
|\partial_i f_j-\partial_jf_i|^2 \leq 2|\partial_i f_j|^2+2|\partial_j f_i|^2
$$
and so
$$
|\nabla \times F|^2\leq 2|\nabla F|^2.
$$
You could maybe get better inequalities with different norms or using some decomposition argument, but this is the most elementary approach I could think of.